# Javascript "Graph" object?

Tags: javascript, object, graph, a-star

I wanted to toy around with A* for the purposes of game making. So I found this little javascript library: https://github.com/bgrins/javascript-astar

This is what the basic usage looks like:

```
var graph = new Graph([
    [1,1,1,1],
    [0,1,1,0],
    [0,0,1,1]
]);
var start = graph.grid[0][0];
var end = graph.grid[1][2];
var result = astar.search(graph, start, end);
```

I digress; I've never seen a "**Graph**" object in Javascript before. I've tried Googling it, and I haven't found anything. I haven't found anything here either. (Maybe I just don't know the right questions to ask?) I looked through the code for the library, and I don't see anything indicating that it's proprietary to the library. It doesn't look like I need to include any other libraries either.

Does anybody know what this is? Is this a native javascript object type? Is it basically the same thing as a 2D array (which is what I've been using so far)?

As always, pointers and advice are always appreciated.

Comment: It is a javascript API which provides an algorithm for searching within a matrix (2D array).

Comment: Got a link or something for me to read?

Comment: `function Graph(gridIn, options) {` is defined in https://github.com/bgrins/javascript-astar/blob/master/astar.js

Comment: So it is... I swear I searched that file for a definition. 

Anyway, thank you for your help.